# Repair or drop rows with extra columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have csv file with 1000 rows.

Each row is supposed to have 5 columns. But few rows have 6 columns due to "\" in the dataset as explained below exaple.

Input data: it looks like below when I open csv file in a text editor.

```
ID, name, description, qty, price 
1, pen, good quality, 4, 5.50
2, book, Good read and\, must, 5, 10
3, PENCIL, good, 5, 100
4, book2, Good read and\, must, 10, 100
```

I want to remove "\" from the file and make all the rows as 5 column data as below.

Required output1:

```
ID, name, description, qty, price 
1, pen, good quality, 4, 5.50
2, book, Good read and must, 5, 10
3, PENCIL, good, 5, 100
4, book2, Good read and must, 10, 100
```

If the above is not possible, I would like to drop the problematic rows which has extra columns(6 rows) and finally make the all the rows as 5 column data.

Required output2:

```
ID, name, description, qty, price 
1, pen, good quality, 4, 5.50
3, PENCIL, good, 5, 100
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### To clean the file:

- read the file
- `replace` "\," with empty string ""
- write back to file
- read to DataFrame if needed

```
with open("data.csv") as file:
    contents = file.read().replace("\\,","")

with open("output.csv", "w+") as file:
    file.write(contents)

#if you want to read to a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("output.csv")

>>> df
   ID     name          description   qty   price 
0   1      pen         good quality     4      5.5
1   2     book   Good read and must     5     10.0
2   3   PENCIL                 good     5    100.0
3   4    book2   Good read and must    10    100.0
```

###### output.csv:

```
ID, name, description, qty, price 
1, pen, good quality, 4, 5.50
2, book, Good read and must, 5, 10
3, PENCIL, good, 5, 100
4, book2, Good read and must, 10, 100
```

##### To drop problematic rows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", error_bad_lines=False)

>>> df
   ID     name    description   qty   price 
0   1      pen   good quality     4      5.5
1   3   PENCIL           good     5    100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `replace` method like so :

```py
data = """
ID, name, description, qty, price 
1, pen, good quality, 4, 5.50
2, book, Good read and\, must, 5, 10
3, PENCIL, good, 5, 100
4, book2, Good read and\, must, 10, 100""".replace("\,", "")
```

Then using `StringIO` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')
>>> df
   ID   name    description         qty price
0   1   pen     good quality        4   5.5
1   2   book    Good read and must  5   10.0
2   3   PENCIL  good                5   100.0
3   4   book2   Good read and must  10  100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way what is making 6 rows is the ',' not \ because it is a Comma Separated File (CSV). To fix this issue you will need to remove all the commas that come after a backslash in your data.

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

file = file.replace("\,", "")

with open('new_file.csv', 'w') as wf:
    wf.write(file)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I have just edited my question.  It should be same number of columns.